# How to remove the bounce on the header?

Tags: javascript, css, fixed, bounce

http://oxfordhigh.oxfordschools.org/ this is the site that im working on and im having a problem with the header. It bounces whenever i scroll it down. This bug only occurs in IE and Chrome but in mozilla it seems fine(as i've checked on my end).

this is the javascript that i've added on the site for the fixed header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(window).scroll(function () {
         if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0 && $(window).width() > 1000) {
        $('#main').css("marginTop", "220px");
        $('.breadcrumb-wrapper').addClass("bread-fix-to-top");
        $('#header').addClass("fix-to-top");
      } else {
        $('#main').css("marginTop", "0");
        $('.breadcrumb-wrapper').removeClass("bread-fix-to-top"); 
        $('#header').removeClass("fix-to-top");
      }
      });
  </script>
```

Any idea on how to fix this kind of issue?

Comment: There is no such thing as `marginTop`. It should be `margin-top`. Try replacing this line `$('#main').css("marginTop", "0");` with `$('#main').css("margin-top", "0");`

Comment: same applies for `$('#main').css("margin-top", "220px");`

Comment: It's the same thing. Didn't change at all.

Comment: @Maverick this usage is valid in jquery, which is known as 'DOM Formatting'.

Comment: create classes with margin-top styles and add/remove it like other classes.

Comment: Got fixed already? Seems fine in both chrome and IE.

Comment: @MennoGouw when your using the mouse wheel to scroll it bounces the header..but when u click the scroll and drag it down it seems fine..

Comment: No it works perfectly while scrolling for me. Do you have latest chrome update?